# Paste as plain text, but also remove any new-line and carriage return characters

Tags: windows, clipboard

I want to copy some text from a webpage or a document and paste it somewhere else after stripping all formatting and whitespace.*** Currently, I do this by:

1. Copy the required text
2. Paste the text in an URL bar of a browser.
3. Copy the text from the URL
4. Paste at the required area

This strips of all new line characters or carriage returns and works perfectly. However, I need a faster way of doing thihs.

***PureText does not help. From their site:

> PureText only removes rich formatting from text. This includes the font face, font style (bold, italics, etc.), font color, paragraph styles (left/right/center aligned), margins, character spacing, bullets, subscript, superscript, tables, charts, pictures, embedded objects, etc. However, it does not modify the actual text. It will not remove or fix new-lines, carriage returns, tabs, or other white-space. It will not fix word-wrap or clean up your paragraphs. If you copy the source code of a web page to the clipboard, it is not going to remove all the HTML tags. If you copy text from an actual web page (not the source of the page), it will remove the formatting.

Answer (score 3):

If it is slow because you are using your mouse or a less efficient keyboard combination, you can speed it up by using the following approach:

1. Highlight the text you want to copy,
2. Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
3. Press and release each of the following keys without releasing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> until you have pressed them all:
   <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Then go to where you want to paste and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Even though you didn't release the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key until completing step #3 above, the computer still interpreted the key commands as:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
  **Copy** the highlighted text
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
  **Highlight** all the text in the search bar
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
  **Paste** your copied text into the search bar
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
  **Select all** text in the search bar
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
  **Copy** text from the search bar

It takes roughly 1 second to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) will do this for you. The following AHK script will paste the contents of the clipboard without formatting by pressing Windows+v. It saves a copy of your existing clipboard, changes the clipboard to be the same without formatting, pastes that and then sets the clipboard back to what it was before.

```
#v::
   Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
   ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%
   Send ^v
   Sleep 300 
   ClipBoard = %Clip0%
   VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)
   Return
```

To use the script, put it in a file with a .ahk extension and double-click it after you've installed Autohotkey.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer (https://superuser.com/a/1634748/1851447), but updated for Autohotkey v2.0:

```
#v::
{
   Clip0 := ClipBoardAll()
   A_ClipBoard := StrReplace(A_ClipBoard, "`r", "")
   A_ClipBoard := StrReplace(A_ClipBoard, "`n", "")
   Send "^v"
   Sleep 300 
   A_ClipBoard := Clip0
   ObjSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)
   Return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier script in AHK 1.1, as the one given [here](https://superuser.com/a/1634748/1851447) ain't always working, is :

```
p::
Send ^f
sleep 300
Send ^c
Return
```